# case sensitive while querying in mongodb

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, collections, case-sensitive

for example i have data like this in my database in mycoll as a collection

```
{id=1,Name:"xxx",rank:1},
{id=2,Name:"Y",rank:2},
{id=3,Nae:"Zzz",rank:3}
```

while writing query  i don't know **name** is written as **Name**,i have simple passed as name like this as i show

```
db. mycoll .find({Name:"xxx"})
```

hence this query returns me 0 records. Because field path which i gave doesn't match  with records in database .help me to write query ignoring case sensitive in field path.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/

Comment: Please mention what all have you tried or researched yet instead of directly asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

To use a case insensitive index on a collection with no default collation, create an index with a collation and set the strength parameter to `1` or `2` like this:

```
db.mycoll.find({ Name:"xxx" }).collation({ locale: 'en', strength: 1 });
```

---

With regards to the value for `strength`:

With `strength: 1`, collation performs comparisons of the base characters only, ignoring other differences such as diacritics and case. This level is also known as the primary level of comparison.

Typically, the primary level is used to denote differences between base characters (for example, "a" < "b"). It is the strongest difference. For example, dictionaries are divided into different sections by base character.

---

With `strength: 2`, collation performs comparisons up to secondary differences, such as diacritics. That is, collation performs comparisons of base characters (primary differences) and diacritics (secondary differences). Differences between base characters takes precedence over secondary differences. This is also known as the secondary level of comparison.

In the secondary level, accents in the characters are considered secondary differences (for example, "as" < "às" < "at"). Other differences between letters can also be considered secondary differences, depending on the language. A secondary difference is ignored when there is a primary difference anywhere in the strings.

---

**N.B.** Check out the official MongoDB docs on [Collation document fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/#collation-document-fields) as well as the [ICU User Guide on comparison levels](http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation/concepts#TOC-Comparison-Levels) for more info about the different values you can set for strength.